# Added Products are showing out of stock

Tags: magento2, products

I added Simple Products in Magento 2.0.7 version and configured them properly like their quantity, price etc but on frontend, products are showing out of stock. I set their quantity 50, price accordingly and mark them as in stock but they are showing out of stock on the frontend.

Can anyone suggest me what i am missing?

Comment: Please check Stock Availability: in stock
This option in inventory section.

Comment: Have you set website and run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I created a cron for reindexing and website for the product is selected as Main Website

Comment: Just remove var folder and check

Comment: Removed folder var.. Nothing happens.

Comment: One thing i noticed is that in Index Management  Section of admin panel, Product EAV showing Reindex Required. Can you please tell me what is Product EAV?

Comment: product eav is all attribute related to product like, image,name,description, color,manufacturer,price,  I think you have to run command for indexing, You just run indexing command from ssh

Comment: Is there any other way to reindex. As i don't know how to run shh and create connectivity with server.

Comment: are you working in local or server? your project are hosted in server?

Comment: No.. Site is on temp domain of my server.

Comment: No otherway is using programatically make script and run script for indexing

Comment: Can you provide me script?

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.. I will try it let you know.. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi... the issue is still there.. can you assist me further more..

Comment: I run that the command you provide me but still it showing Required Reindexing for Product EAV

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. Rakesh it works. I run the command again and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check your product inventory section [image]

Comment: Inventory section setting is same as you described in screenshot.

Comment: Why do they have an inventory AND a 'Stock Availability' flag? Seems redundant.

Comment: colefner It's possible to have 0 items in stock but still want to show it as saleable, that's backorders.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your item has a weight, if you set it has weight otherwise magento2 without telling you will consider it a "virtual product" which screws up the in stock check because magento2.